# polynomial regression in R: how to add hard constraints (go through specified points)?

Tags: r, regression, polynomial, constrained-regression

I'd like to perform polynomial regression on my data (which lies in [0,10]), but I need to ensure that the endpoints of the range are fixed, i.e. that the curve goes through (0,0) and (10,10). So the interpolant

$y = a + bx + cx^2 + \epsilon$

becomes

$y = bx + cx^2 + \epsilon$
with 
$b = 1 - 10c$.

Assuming just quadratic for now, although I might go to a cubic if the data warrants it. 
But how do I express this constraint during fitting?

Comment: Do you want any random components in your data? If yes, the description is needed.

Comment: Ah, it's only the interpolant that I need, thinking about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easiest just to plug your constraint into the model and rewrite it:

$y = bx + cx^2 = (1  - 10c)x + cx^2 = x + c(x^2 - 10x)$

Regress $y-x$ against $x^2 - 10x$, without an intercept, to get $c$.  Then you can compute $b$ from that.